# Run python script from R

Tags: python, r, windows, arcgis

I´m trying to run a python script from R using `system()` function:

```
system('D:/python script.py', wait=T)
```

The script runs well by itself (double click on it), but when I call it from R it doesn't run and I get the following message:

```
Warning message:
running command 'D:/python script.py' had status 127
```

When I try to run it using `shell.exec('python script.py')`, it runs perfectly. However, I need to wait the command to finish, to follow to the next line of the code. The argument 'wait' from `system()`, `system2()`, or `shell()` allows me to do that, but `shell.exec()` doesn't have a similar argument.

This is the code of my python script applying the Tabulate Area function from ArcGIS:

```
# Importing libraries
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Script arguments
Zone_Raster = "D:/Zone_Raster.tif"
Sp_Raster = "D:/Value_Raster.tif"
Tab_Area = "D:/Tab_Area.dbf"

# Tabulate area
TabulateArea(Zone_Raster,"VALUE",Sp_Raster,"VALUE",Tab_Area,"#")
```

I've also tried calling a .bat file where I pass the arguments to the python script as `sys.argv`. The .bat file runs perfectly by itself (double clic on it), but when I call it using `system()` or `shell()` it doesn't run and returns this message:

```
'python script.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Does any body known how to run the python script or the .bat file using `system()`, `system2()`, or `shell()`? Or how I can make that `shell.exec()` waits the command to finish?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Jaime

Comment: Why not try using the `reticulate` package to avoid a system call?

Comment: The script name has a space in it? `'D:/python script.py'` looks like you are trying to run a program named "python" with a parameter "script.py". I assume this is Windows? You'll need to escape the space. Try `'D:/python\\ script.py'` or `'"D:/python script.py"'`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I put that name on the example, but neither the orinal name of the script nor the directory have spaces.

Comment: I´have tried with `py_run_file()` from `reticulate` but I get this error: `Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
  Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded`

Comment: Thanks again MrFlick, you were right. I've made many attempts that I forgot that I changed the code to write the python scripts and they were creating with a space. Using `shell('"D:/python script.py"')` works perfect.