# run python script within R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have 'hello_world.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

print('hello world')
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3]})
df
df.to_csv('hello.csv')
```

I would like to call this script from and R script.

Using `shell` from [Run python script from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077619/run-python-script-from-r) did not work --> running `shell('"python hello_world.py"')` gave me the following error:

```
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Using `system('python hello_world.py')` returned the same error, as suggested by [how to call python script from R with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638558/how-to-call-python-script-from-r-with-arguments)

Using reticulate as per [Calling Python from R with reticulate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213001/calling-python-from-r-with-reticulate-package) and

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_file('hello_world.py')
```

returned:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Including the extra line `!pip install pandas` produced a syntax error:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
    File "<string>", line 1
    !pip install pandas
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there something I am missing? Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

[Importing Python package (pandas) from R with Reticulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741751/importing-python-package-pandas-from-r-with-reticulate)

```
reticulate::py_module_available("pandas") ## Returned FALSE
reticulate::py_install("pandas")
py_run_file('hello_world.py')
```